# Como vocês calculam (com facilidade) total e subtotal no Django?

Tags: django

Estou usando Django 1.7.8

Eu tenho o models.py

```
class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('quantidade'))
    price_sale = models.DecimalField(

    def get_subtotal(self):
        return self.price_sale * self.quantity

    subtotal = property(get_subtotal)
```

./manage.py shell

```
>>> from vendas_project.vendas.models import SaleDetail
>>> from django.db.models import Sum, F, FloatField
>>> q = SaleDetail.objects.values('price_sale', 'quantity').filter(sale=1)
>>> q.aggregate(Sum(F('price_sale') * F('quantity')), output_field=FloatField())
```

Gera o erro:

```
field_list = aggregate.lookup.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
AttributeError:
    'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Como vocês calculam subtotais e total no Django?

Eu preciso do resultado, exemplo:

```
price_sale quantity subtotal

10.50      2        21.00

9.55       3        28.65

total = 49.65
```

Comment: Isso que você quer [está disponível no Django 1.8](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030), mas não no 1.7 ou anterior. Mais de dois anos atrás eu tive um problema semelhante (no sentido de ter a mesma causa raiz), e postei [essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15453662/520779), até hoje sem resposta. Infelizmente, não conheço nenhuma solução pré 1.8 que não envolva usar `extra` (posso dar mais detalhes numa resposta, se quiser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Para o Django 1.8 ou mais recente, ver a [resposta do Orion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66679/215).

Na versão 1.7 do Django ou anterior não é possível utilizar `F` como parâmetro de `annotate`, `aggregate` ou `values` (ver [ticket #14030](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030)), de modo que a única maneira de fazer isso é utilizando SQL puro (via `extra`). Não sei se é possível calcular total e subtotal em uma única query. Um exemplo (testado no SQLite) é:

```
>>> SaleDetail.objects.extra(select={
...   'subtotal':'round(price_sale * quantity, 2)',
... }).values('price_sale', 'quantity', 'subtotal')
[{'subtotal': 21.0, 'price_sale': Decimal('10.5'), 'quantity': 2},
 {'subtotal': 28.65, 'price_sale': Decimal('9.55'), 'quantity': 3}]

>>> SaleDetail.objects.extra(select={
...   'total':'round(sum(price_sale * quantity), 2)',
... }).values('total')
[{'total': 49.65}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Na versão 1.8 para gerar o subtotal você deve utilizar `annotate` e para gerar o total você deve usar `aggregate`.

> É necessário utilizar **ExpressionWrapper** quando estiver realizando
>   cálculos com diferentes tipos de valores.

Exemplo:

```
>>> from django.db.models import F, DecimalField, ExpressionWrapper
>>> q = SaleDetail.objects.filter(sale=1).values('price_sale', 'quantity')
>>> q_com_subtotal = q.annotate(subtotal=ExpressionWrapper(F('price_sale') * F('quantity')), output_field=DecimalField())
>>> q_com_subtotal[0].subtotal
21.0
>>> calculo_total = q_com_subtotal.aggregate(total=Sum('subtotal'))
>>> calculo_total.total
49.65
```

Referências:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#query-expressions
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper

Comment: primeiro deuo seguinte erro: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field. Dai eu coloquei qs = q.annotate(subtotal=(F('price_sale') * F('quantity')), output_field=FloatField())
qs[0].subtotal
E o erro passou a ser: AttributeError: 'FloatField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'

Comment: @RegisdaSilva já atualizei o código.